# Help break down「他人に提供した財産・労力と報酬と受け取る財産上」

Tags: particle-と, parsing

I'm trying to understand the definition of「対価に見合う」and I'm uncertain about the bold part

> 「対価に見合う（見合った）」の意味
>
> **他人に提供した財産・労力と報酬と受け取る財産上**の利益が見合っているという意味です。

Does this dot・mean "and" or "or"?

I think the first と in「他人に提供した財産・労力と報酬」is short for「と引き換えに」and I'm not sure about the と before 受け取る. I think it is interchangeable with を.

I wonder if this is the correct way to parse?

> （（他人に提供した財産）・（労力）と（報酬）と受け取る）財産上．．．

What's wrong with my understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the definition of [対価](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%AF%BE%E4%BE%A1)(essentially the 3rd item below) and syntax of 見合う, it would be natural to parse it as

- 他人に提供した (財産・労力) *(property and/or labor) provided to someone*
- と *and*
- 受け取る財産上の利益 *received benefit in terms of property*
- が見合っている *are balanced*

見合う is usually used as 報酬**が**労力**に**見合わない or 報酬**と**労力**が**見合わない (or 労力と報酬が見合わない). That said, it is possible to think that 労力と引き換えに受け取る報酬が見合わない (in the sense that it wouldn't sound particularly odd).

Another hint that helps parse would be that 提供する is an antonym of 受け取る here.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to explain the second と between 報酬 and 受け取る財産上の利益.

Comment: @aguijonazo You mean the second と is different from the first one?

Comment: @JimmyYang - I would simply read if as ［Aと［BとC］］が見合っている for lack of a better alternative while finding the sentence a bit odd because there seems to be no good reason to list 報酬 and 受け取る財産上の利益 side by side. It could be a typo of 報酬として. In any case, my comment above was because that part seemed to be completely ignored.

Comment: I was missing ...労力と**報酬と**受け取る, but it should be a typo for 報酬として. Maybe [this site](http://ikikatadatabase.com/archives/6207)? Seems like the definition of 対価を得る (just above the quoted def) also has a typo, 受け取る should be removed.